# How to use the function attribute as an attribute of the onclick event (input element)?

Tags: javascript, html, function, onclick, attributes

Let's say I have the code below:

```js
function addValue(x){

    var button = document.createElement( "input" );
    button.setAttribute("type", "submit");
    button.setAttribute("src", "images/repeatStageIcon.png");
    button.setAttribute("class", "option-image");
    button.setAttribute("title", "Repeat Current Stage!");

    //HOW TO PASS X AS AN ONCLICK ATTRIBUTE?
    button.setAttribute("onclick", "createRepeatStage( x )");

    var p = document.getElementById("myDiv");
    p.appendChild(button);
}

function createRepeatStage( thisX ){
   alert(thisX);
}

addValue(6);
```

```html
<html>

  <body>
  
     <div id="myDiv"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**QUESTION:**

How to pass the **x** attribute in the onclick event so that when the method **createRepeatStage(x);** is called, the **x** value would be passed in that method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript event handler with parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10000083/javascript-event-handler-with-parameters)

Comment: An efficient way to do it. Although is not necessary in my case, as I want something simple. Thanks though for your answer @GeorgeJempty

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Set OnClick attribute with value containing function in ie8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019078/how-to-set-onclick-attribute-with-value-containing-function-in-ie8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap the handler in another function.

```
button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  createRepeatStage(x);
});
```

The value of x will be preserved by the [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures).

Note, I've used `addEventListener` instead of `setAttribute`.

```js
function addValue(x){

    var button = document.createElement( "input" );
    button.setAttribute("type", "submit");
    button.setAttribute("src", "images/repeatStageIcon.png");
    button.setAttribute("class", "option-image");
    button.setAttribute("title", "Repeat Current Stage!");

    //HOW TO PASS X AS AN ONCLICK ATTRIBUTE?
    button.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
      createRepeatStage(x);
    });

    var p = document.getElementById("myDiv");
    p.appendChild(button);
}

function createRepeatStage( thisX ){
   alert(thisX);
}

addValue(6);
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
     <div id="myDiv"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

## Using bind

If, for some reason, you're against wrapping your handler in a function, you can take advantage of [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind).

```js
function addValue(x){
    var button = document.createElement( "input" );
    button.setAttribute("type", "submit");
    button.setAttribute("src", "images/repeatStageIcon.png");
    button.setAttribute("class", "option-image");
    button.setAttribute("title", "Repeat Current Stage!");

    //HOW TO PASS X AS AN ONCLICK ATTRIBUTE?
    button.addEventListener("click", createRepeatStage.bind(null, x));

    var p = document.getElementById("myDiv");
    p.appendChild(button);
}

function createRepeatStage( thisX ){
   alert(thisX);
}

addValue(6);
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
     <div id="myDiv"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: very logical answer. Thanks a lot @Raphael Rafatpanah

Comment: @LoizosVasileiou I've also added an example using `bind`, but I would personally use the first example.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, there are two things to fix in your page.

1. you cannot evaluate the addValue function before the page loads, since there would be no `myDiv` element. A standard way to execute code after the page is loaded is to use the `onLoad` attribute in the `body` element. That is:

```
    <body onload="addValue(6)">
        <h1>Hola</h1>

        <div id="myDiv"></div>
    </body>
```

2. how to indicate to the new button the "onclick" handler. You can just assign the `onclick` attribute of the button:

```
            function addValue(x){

                var button = document.createElement( "input" );
                button.setAttribute("type", "submit");
                button.setAttribute("class", "option-image");
                button.setAttribute("title", "Repeat Current Stage!");

                //HOW TO PASS X AS AN ONCLICK ATTRIBUTE?
                button.onclick = () => createRepeatStage( x );

                var p = document.getElementById("myDiv");
                p.appendChild(button);
            }
```

Note that you can pass an arrow function, it is a compressed form ... though it could not work on (really) older browsers. To be sure that your code runs everywhere, you can use the "traditional" function syntax

```
            function addValue(x){

                var button = document.createElement( "input" );
                button.setAttribute("type", "submit");
                button.setAttribute("class", "option-image");
                button.setAttribute("title", "Repeat Current Stage!");

                //HOW TO PASS X AS AN ONCLICK ATTRIBUTE?
                button.onclick = function() { createRepeatStage( x ) };

                var p = document.getElementById("myDiv");
                p.appendChild(button);
            }
```

Hope it helps - Carlos

PS: possibly the other button settings could/should be replaced by direct attribute assignment - Carlos

Comment: Even better way for my example. I didnt know about arrow functions. Thanks @Carlos Lombardi

Comment: To be honest the arrow function works for me where the "traditional syntax" is not. I use Google Chrome Version 72.0.3626.109